# Find the values of $a$, for which this system of linear equations has one solution, no solution, or infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Determine the values of a for which the following system of linear equations has no solutions, a unique solution, or infinitely many solutions. You can select 'always', 'never', '$a = $', or '$a \neq$', then specify a value or comma-separated list of values.
$$
\begin{align}
2x−6y−4z  &=  16\\
ax−y−4z  &=  6\\
2x−3y−4z  &=  10
\end{align}
$$
This is a problem for my Linear Algebra class, and I can't seem to figure out how to get it into RREF and evaluate.

Comment: Where exactly are you running into trouble?

Comment: Since $-4z$ is common, it's easy enough to reduce this to a system of two variable equations by subracting them from each other. Go from there.

Answer (score 1):

The criterion to have solutions is is that the matrix of coefficients of the linear system and the augmented matrix have the same rank. This common rank is then the `codimension` of the affine space of solutions.

So let's perform row reduction on the augmented matrix:
\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2&-6&-4&16\\
a&-1&-4&6\\2&-3&-4&10
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-3&-2&8\\ 2&-3&-4&10 \\
a&-1&-4&6
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-3&-2&8\\ 0&3&0&-6 \\
0&3a-1&2a-4&6-8a
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow\\
\rightsquigarrow&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-3&-2&8\\ 0&1&0&-2 \\
0&3a-1&2a-4&6-8a
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-3&-2&8\\ 0&1&0&-2 \\
0&0&2a-4&4-2a
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&-2&2\\ 0&1&0&-2 \\
0&0&a-2&2-a
\end{array}\right]
\end{align}

- if $a\ne2$, we can proceed as follows:
  $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&-2&2\\ 0&1&0&-2 \\
  0&0&1&-1
  \end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&-2 \\
  0&0&1&-1
  \end{array}\right] $$
  There is a unique solution (the last column) since the matrix has full rank.
- If $a=2$, we have a row reduced echelon form:
  $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&-2&2\\ 0&1&0&-2 \\
  0&0&0&0
  \end{array}\right]$$
  which shows, as the matrix and the augmented matrix have rank $2$ has; as  a set of solutions, an affine space of dimension $3-2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

With $$z=\frac{1}{2}(x-3y-8)$$ (from the first equation) we get
$$x(a-2)+5y=-10$$ and $$y=-2$$ in the third equation, so we obtain
$$x(a-2)=0$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks! Would this mean that if a=2 the system has infinite solutions?

Comment: And if "a" does not equal 2, there is a unique solution?

Comment: That would it mean, since we have $$x\cdot 0=0$$ in this case!

Comment: If $$a\neq 2$$ then we get $$x=0$$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let the equations be $(1), (2), (3)$ in the order you show.

Perform the following three calculations:

$(1)-(2)$

$(1)-(3)$

$(3)-(2)$

The rest should fall out quite nicely.