# If the row echelon form of a linear equation system has a line with zero entries, then it has more than a solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> If the row echelon form of a linear equation system has a line with zero entries, then it has
>   more than one solution.

Let
\begin{align}
\text{I}& \qquad 3x_1&=2\\
\text{II}& \qquad 0x_1&=0
\end{align} a linear equation system in row echelon form and a line with zero entries.

If we solve this equation system, the solution $\mathcal{L}$ would be $\mathcal{L}=\{x_1=\frac23\}$. Contradiction. The statement is wrong.

---

This looks way too easy. Is there anything I might forgot about?

**EDIT**:

> If the row echelon form of a linear system of equations has a column with zero entries, it has no solution.

This statement is wrong (too), right?

Comment: The statement is true for an $n{\times}n$ linear system.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused. There are no limitations given in the statement. It could be any linear system I would say. So in general, the statement is wrong but true for $n\times n$ linear systems?

Comment: @Bernard what do you think?

Comment: Let me think a moment  if I can give a complete general answer.

Comment: @Bernard thank you! I've added a similar question below that I'm not quite sure about.

Comment: The general answer is interms of rank of the matrix of coefficients and rank of the augmented matrix. You can take a look at my answer to this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106550/find-the-values-of-a-for-which-this-system-of-linear-equations-has-one-soluti/3106612#3106612) for a detailed statement.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the linear system $Ax=b$. You can form the matrix $[A\mid b]$ and perform row reduction to get, say, the row echelon form $[U\mid c]$.

The system has at least a solution if and only if $c$ is not a pivot column. In this case,

> the system has a single solution if and only if every column in $U$ is a pivot column

independently on the number of zero rows in $[U\mid c]$.

If the system has more unknowns than equations, then, as soon as it has a solution it will have infinitely many of them, because it's impossible that every column in $U$ is a pivot column.

The case when the system has a single solution and there are zero rows in $[U|c]$ is possible when the system has more equations than unknowns. The example you present is indeed one of these.

The statement “if the row echelon form has a zero column then the system has no solution” is clearly false. If the system has a solution at all, it will have infinitely many of them, because the unknown corresponding to the zero column can get whatever value you want.

Comment: To sum it up, my first proof is fine and to proof the second statement, I'll need to take any linear equation system and add a zero column to it. Then I will look for a solution of the system that contradicts the statement, right?

Comment: @Doesbaddel Yes, I think you nailed it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thank you!