# Finding values of $a$ which this system of linear equations has one, no solution, or infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

Given the following equation:

$x+ay -z = 1$

$x+y -az = a$

$2x-4y +2az = -2$

Determine the value of $a$ (if any) for which the system has no solutions.

Determine the value of $a$ (if any) for which the system has exactly one solution.

Determine the value of $a$ (if any) for which the system has infinitely many solutions

And in case the system has infinite solutions, find them

So I'd like to put the coefficients of $x,y,z$ into a matrix like the following:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & -a \\ 2  & 4 & 2a \end{pmatrix}$

And I want to do this by the method of checking when the determinant not equals to $0$.

So I calculate it and got to a place where $(a-1)(-4a-6)$ which means that $1$ or $-3/2$ will zero the determinant.

So I realize that if $a$ will be $0$ or $3/2$ then the system has no solutions,

but then I don't know how to continue,

How do I find out about the unique infinitely soulutions? I guess for unique solution $a$ needs to be not $0$ or $3/2$
but for some reason I can't put it all together..

Comment: See, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818997/determine-the-values-of-k-so-that-the-following-linear-system-has-unique-infi?rq=1, also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106550/find-the-values-of-a-for-which-this-system-of-linear-equations-has-one-soluti?rq=1.  See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2944003/9003,

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the determinant of the system's matrix:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -a \\
2 & 4 & 2a \\
\end{vmatrix} = -4a^2+6a-2
$$

You must know that, if that determinant is different from $0$, then the system has unique solution. When it's $0$, it can either have infinite or none. Let's calculate the values which make the determinant be $0$:

$$-4a^2+6a-2=0 \ \implies \ a=\frac{1}{2},\ a=1.$$

So now you can conclude that the system has unique solution when $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{1}{2},1\}$. Now the only work you have left is to study what happends when $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and what when $a=1$ separately.

Comment: So the work left for me is put each value in his turn into the regular matrix and check how many solutions it has? I tought that if determinant equals 0 the matrix has no solution for some reason, didn't remember that it can also be inifinte while the determinant is 0

Comment: @Ciniminis yes, now you have to substitute that values of $a$ in your system and check is the system has infinite or none solutions. If the determinant of the matrix is $0$, then the column vectors of it aren't linearly independent and then they can lead to a vector space that either don't has the solution vector, or either has infinte different ways to obtain it ar lineal combinations of the column vectors. Sorry if I dind't explained it too clear.